# Wordpress page content to be displayed in non WP site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I have created a mobile site using content from a wordpress page.

The page takes information from the database like this

```
$sql="          SELECT  p.post_title, p.post_content
                FROM    they_posts AS p
                WHERE   p.ID='".$id."'
            ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    /*Title*/
    echo '<h1>'.$row['post_title'].'</h1><hr>';

    /*content*/
    $cont = $row['post_content'];

    echo $cont;
}
```

The page doesn't keep its indentation / formatting from the wordpress page.
I have also tried putting html tags in the page to see if that would change the format in my page to no avail.

Is there a way to keep all paragraphs and page links on my page?

Thank you

Comment: use `echo htmlentities($cont)`

Comment: That isnt really doing it, it just displays info like this:
Test&lt;br&gt; Line Break&lt;br&gt; information

Comment: try `echo nl2br( stripslashes ( $cont ) );`

Comment: See:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Thank you Tamil, that seems to have done the trick for the most part. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try a CSS fix.

```
.your-content {
     white-space: pre-line;
}
```

The other way would be to format your $cont and add 
 everytime you find a break point. Like this:

```
$cont = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$cont);
```